# MATLAB loop through excel files

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

My code is posted below. It does exactly what I need it to do.

It reads in a file and plots the data that I need. If I want to read in another file and have it go through the same code, without having to write the whole thing a second time with different variables, is that possible? I would like to store the matrices from each loop.

As you can see the file I get is called: Oxygen_1keV_300K.xlsx

I have another file called: Oxygen_1keV_600K.xlsx

and so on.

How can I loop through these files without having to re-code the whole thing? I then want to plot them all on the same graph. It would be nice to store the final matrix Y and Ymean for each file so they are not overwritten.

```
clear
clc


files = ['Oxygen_1keV_300K','Oxygen_1keV_300K','Oxygen_1keV_600K','Oxygen_1keV_900K'];
celldata = cellstr(file)

k = cell(1,24);
for k=1:24
   data{k} = xlsread('C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Oxygen_1keV_300K.xlsx',['PKA', num2str(k)]);
end

for i=1:24
xfinal{i}=data{1,i}(end,1);
xi{i}=0:0.001:xfinal{i};
xi{i}=transpose(xi{i});

x{i}=data{1,i}(:,1);
y{i}=data{1,i}(:,4);
yi{i} = interp1(x{i},y{i},xi{i});
end

Y = zeros(10001, numel(data));
for ii = 1 : numel(data)
    Y(:, ii) = yi{ii}(1 : 10001);
end


Ymean = mean(Y, 2);

figure (1)
x=0:0.001:10;
semilogy(x,Ymean)
```

Comment: I suggest using the [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) or [`ls`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html) functions to get a list of the files and then using a for loop to loop through them.

Comment: I dont want to get all the files in the directory. I was thinking of just creating Ymean{i}. How can I just give a list of the files I want to loop through?

Comment: You can also define a cell array of the file path strings manually and loop over that.

Comment: how??  not sure how to do that

Comment: What is the size and type of your Ymean right now?

Comment: Its 10,001. I just need to define a cell array and add it to my xlsread right? Then I can create Ymean{i}. How do I load the loop of different file names into my xlsread?

Comment: I added a cell array (check my code). How can I load those 3 files within a loop and just create Ymean{i}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell arrays make it very easy to store a list of strings that you can access as part of a for loop. In this case, I would suggest putting your file paths in a cell array as a substitute for the string used in your `xlsread` call

For example,

```
%The first file is the same as in your example.
%I just made up file names for the next two. 
%Use the full file path if the file is not in your current directory
filepath_list = {'C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Oxygen_1keV_300K.xlsx', 'file2.xlsx', 'file3.xlsx'};

%To store separate results for each file, make Ymean a cell array or matrix too
YMean = zeros(length(filepath_list), 1);

%Now use a for loop to loop over the files
for ii=1:length(filepath_list)
   %Here's where your existing code would go 
   %I only include the sections which change due to the loop
   for k=1:24
      %The change is that on this line you use the cell array variable to load the next file path
      data{k} = xlsread(filepath_list{ii},['PKA', num2str(k)]);
   end
   % ... do the rest of your processing 
   %You'll need to index into Ymean to store your result in the corresponding location
   YMean(ii) = mean(Y, 2);
end
```

Cell arrays are a basic matlab variable type. For an introduction, I recommend the documentation [for creating](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html) and [accessing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) data in cell arrays.

If all your files are in the same directory, you can also use functions like [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html?searchHighlight=dir&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) or [`ls`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html?searchHighlight=ls&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to populate the cell array programatically.

Comment: I just used the file name in my example, but if the files are not in your current directory, simply use the full file path where I use the file names. I'll edit the example.

Comment: I see. Can you clarify how I edit Ymean to be part of the loop? Currently Ymean will just be the last loop. How do I store Ymean for each loop ? Is it just Ymean{ii}

Comment: You'll need to define Ymean as a cell array or matrix too. I just added to the example.

Comment: Couple of things I am working on fixing...You have file path_list which should be filepath_list. Also, you used a ii loop but I already had an ii loop

Comment: I tried to fix it but I keep getting errors. Could you add my code to your answer so the loops dont overwrite each other?

Comment: i tried myself but i get this error: Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Error in compare_v3 (line 31)
YMean{uu} = mean(Y, 2);

Comment: Hi Jack, I'm sorry about  the typos in my code. I'm happy to correct them. However, since I don't have your files, I can neither run nor debug the main body of your code. My code has comments showing where your code should go. You should be learning how to debug your own code as part of your matlab experience. If you continue to struggle with this problem, I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: Yes my code went there but it does not work I believe because I have two ii loops now. I already had an ii loop and then you created one. The YMean variable was just returning 0.

Comment: Then change the name of the variable, it can be jj instead of ii. Variable names are not magic.

Comment: I did change it. and i said i got this error: Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Error in compare_v3 (line 31)
YMean{uu} = mean(Y, 2);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149642/discussion-between-cecilia-and-jack).